# Lua userdata gc

Tags: lua, garbage-collection, lua-userdata

Is it possible for a piece of Lua userdata to hold reference to a Lua object? (Like a table, or another piece of userdata?). Basically, what I want to know is:

Can I create a piece of userdata in such a way taht when the gc runs, the user data can say: "Hey! I'm holding references to these other objects, mark them as well."

EDIT: responding to lhf:

Suppose I have:

```
struct Vertex {
  double x, y, z;
}

struct Quaternion {
  double w, x, y, z;
}
```

Now, I can do:

```
struct Foo {
  Vertex v;
  Quaternion q;
}
```

but suppose instead I want:

```
struct Bar {
  Vertex *v;
  Quaternion *q;
}
```

[i.e. suppose Vertex & Quaternion are really big pieces of userdata].

Now, suppose I have a Lua user function that takes a userdata Vertex, and a userdata Quaternion, and creates a userdata Bar (I don't want a userdata Foo since I want to save the space) -- then I need somehow for the userdata Vertex*/Quaternion* to not be gc-ed.

Comment: It seems convoluted. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @lhf: does the above edit make sense?

Comment: That's a different question now. The short answer is not to mix two styles of memory management: explicit in C vs automatic in Lua. See Norman's answer.

Comment: How is that a different question? The point is that "Bar" now needs to say -- hey, this Vertex*/Quaternion* I'm pointing to, in the lua heap, also needs to be marked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for a piece of lua user data to hold reference to a lua object?

**No.** A userdata can't hold a pointer to another Lua object.  If you want to use a userdata to keep another Lua object alive, you have to do it using **weak tables**.  Roberto's book as a [section on how to do it](http://www.lua.org/pil/17.html).

Comment: "Strong tables" are tables where key & value are checked when gc-ing. How does weak tables factor in with userdata? Can you explain more?

Comment: You put the userdata in the table along with the Lua value(s) that you're trying to keep alive.  Roberto's book is online and explains it all.

Comment: Why would I use a weak table instead of a strong table then?

Comment: Because when the GC runs, if the weak table is the only reference, your userdata will be collected, and it will then stop keeping other objects alive.

Comment: The clarification needed is then: Keep a mapping from userdata to 'other objects', with weak storage of the mapping keys.

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I did anything with lua. I think that if the data referenced was created by the lua machine, then it will clean it up itself. Otherwise you must wait for the gc callback in your C code and free the memory yourself.